# zoom out Google map reveals another map, sometimes with my markers; angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm a web dev student trying to use Google Maps in an Angular app. I can create new markers with a form but I'm getting a glitchy display problem wherein my markers show up sometimes and other times they aren't there. BUT when they aren't there I can zoom out until the map shrinks to the point where it reveals another map which does have my markers.

This image below my code shows an example when my markers did show up, but there is still a mystery map underneath and this time it has one random marker. Anyone know what's going on? Here's how I'm calling the map and adding markers. Apologies for all my newbie hacks.

```
  function cityFactoryFunction($resource){
    var factory = $resource("http://localhost:3000/cities/:id.json", {}, {
      update: {method: "PUT"}
    });
    factory.createMarker = function(info, myMap){
      var markers = [];
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var address = info.address;
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: myMap,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            title: info.city
          });
          marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div>';
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + info.name + '</h2>' + marker.content);
            infoWindow.open(myMap, marker);
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
      });
    };
    return factory;
  }

  function welcomeCtrlFunction(CityFactory){
    var vm = this;
    vm.cities = CityFactory.query();
    // creates initial map
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.90529, -77.02489),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    // cycles through json making clickable map markers
    vm.cities.$promise.then(function(response){
      for (i = 0; i < vm.cities.length; i++){
        CityFactory.createMarker(vm.cities[i], myMap);
      }
    });

    // creates the markers' info windows
    openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker){
      e.preventDefault();
      google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    };
    vm.newCity = new CityFactory();
  }

  // custom form directive
  function cityFormFunction(CityFactory){
    var vm = this;
    return{
      templateUrl: "city.form.html",
      scope: {
        city: "=",
        formMethod: "@"
      },
      link: function(scope){
        scope.create = function(){
          CityFactory.save(scope.city, function(response){
            console.log(response);
            CityFactory.push(response);
            CityFactory.createMarker(response);
          });
        };
      }
    };
  }
```

[image: Google maps zoomed way out]

Comment: This was resolved. Somehow I was inadvertently calling for two maps to be created and their API requests were getting mixed up in the asynchronous geocode requests.